# Droping rows with outliers from specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, outliers, drop

I am building a binary classification model on a heavily unbalanced dataset(95% 1s and 5% 0s). I want to drop the rows with outliers and I used the below code:

```
from scipy import stats
df=df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

However, this code is dropping the rows that have my label 0. Is there a better way of dropping rows with outliers for all columns except the label column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (assume your label is located in `df["label"]`):

```
df = df[(df["label"] == 0) | (np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

The first condition will keep all rows with `df["label"] == 0` disregard of the `zscore`.